# What is maximum auto_increment value on DOUBLE column?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

MySQL allows an auto_increment definition on a `DOUBLE` column.

What is the maximum allowed value for this auto_increment column?

**SQLFiddle:**
**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9be033/1**

Comment: is column of `DOUBLE` type allowed to have auto_increment? I didn't know that.

Comment: Yes. I created the sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9be033/1

Answer (score 0):

Double has a range which is -1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0, and 2.2250738585072014E-308 to 1.7976931348623157E+308.

That being said, it is usually recommended to use INT or BIGINT or SMALLINT(*whole number*) when you are using [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). Using double for auto_increment will not be a very good idea since you have to take care of double precision value in that case.